# Merged Cells Messing Up VBA Code Regarding Cell Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have the basic problem (which had already been answered a hundred times) on how to allow the user to only select a single cell at a time (prevent multiple cells being active). If the user tried, it would redirect the active selection to a specific cell (B1). Based on a quick google search, intelligent copy and pasting, and some slight edits, this is what I end up with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

     '>> Prevent user from multiple selections

    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Multiple Selection Disabled, refer to B1"
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

A simple code. However, the problem I run into is that whenever I select a merged cell, the code triggers since the selection is, according to excel, more than one cell. How do I go around this? Thanks.

I've inherited this file from another person, so there was already a lot of merged cells. And my worksheet is highly automatized and VBA rich. Asking me to remove all merged cells is (practically) not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range.MergeCells` will return `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `Null` depending on the range

- `TRUE` if Range is a single Merged range and nothing else
- `FALSE` if Range consists of non-merged cells only
- `Null` anything else, ie a Merged range plus one or more other cells (merged or otherwise)

To utilise this consider

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.MergeCells Or IsNull(Target.MergeCells) Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Multiple Selection Disabled, refer to B1"
            Me.Cells(1, "B").Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Range (and Selection) objects have the MergeCells property, which is a boolean indicating whether the range contains any merged cells. [See the docs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197310.aspx)

This means you could check whether `Selection.MergeCells` is `True` before continuing to redirect the selection.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

It helps to know that there's such a property.
So thanks for that. However, a user can now select multiple merged cells without being redirected. Any way I could prevent that? Thanks!

Comment: Testing on Excel 2016, MergeCells returns Null if multiple merged cells are selected; True if a single merged cell is selected; False if any number of unmerged cells are selected. Test this in whatever version you're using. If it still applies, that provides the mechanism you need.

Comment: I tested it already, the user could now select multiple merged cells (I'm using Excel 2013).
I'm now researching into something along the lines of "number of merged cells" <> 1, Redirect. But still researching. Any more help would be appreciated.
Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it has been solved fully more quickly by the other answer. This was a great help though.